# JSON and Eclipse - Why is an exception being thrown?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, lwjgl, slick2d

I know a fair amount about java but am new to Slick2d and JSON. I cannot figure out why an exception is being thrown when trying to load the .json map file. I am using eclipse, slick2d, lwjgl and json. I built a map file and it is located in eclipse under res/maps/
Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
at cardboard.world.World.load(World.java:33)
at cardboard.Engine.initStatesList(Engine.java:49)
at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
at cardboard.Engine.main(Engine.java:31)
```

Here is the executing code

```
try {
        World.load("res/maps/world.json");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Map does not exist");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Here is the World class

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet;

import cardboard.Resources;

public class World {

public static Image[][] solids;
public static int WIDTH;
public static int HEIGHT;

public static void load(String path) throws Exception {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(path));
    JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) obj;

    JSONArray layers = (JSONArray) jObj.get("layers");
    int amount = layers.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        JSONObject layer = (JSONObject) layers.get(i);
        String type = (String) layer.get("name");

        if (type.equals("solids")) {
            solids = parse((JSONArray)layer.get("data"));
        } else if (type.equals("spawns")) {
            // Spawn point code
        }
    }

}

private static Image[][] parse(JSONArray arr) {

    Image[][] layer = new Image [WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    int index;

    for (int y = 0; y < WIDTH; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < HEIGHT; x++) {
            index = (int)((long)arr.get((y * WIDTH) + x));
            layer[x][y] = getSpriteImage(index);
        }
    }

    return layer;
}

private static Image getSpriteImage(int index) {
    if (index == 0) return null;
    index -= 1;

    SpriteSheet sheet = Resources.getSprite("tileset");
    //int vertical = sheet.getVerticalCount();
    int horizontal = sheet.getHorizontalCount();

    int y = (index / horizontal); //vert?
    int x = (index % horizontal);

    return sheet.getSubImage(x, y);
}
}
```

Eclipse is throwing no errors I am just getting the error message I wrote "Map does not exist" It would be super if you could take a look! Thanks

In case you need Resources.java

```
package cardboard;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.Sound;
import org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet;

import cardboard.world.Tile;

public class Resources {

private static Map<String, Image> images;
private static Map<String, SpriteSheet> sprites;
private static Map<String, Sound> sounds;

public Resources() {

    images = new HashMap<String, Image>();
    sprites = new HashMap<String, SpriteSheet>();
    sounds = new HashMap<String, Sound>();

    try {
        sprites.put("tileset", loadSprite("res/tileset.png",  Tile.SMALL_SIZE, Tile.SMALL_SIZE));
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Image loadImage(String path) throws SlickException {
    return new Image(path, false, Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
}

public static SpriteSheet loadSprite(String path, int tw, int th) throws    SlickException {
    return new SpriteSheet(loadImage(path), tw, th);
}

public static SpriteSheet getSprite(String getter) {
    return sprites.get(getter);
}

public static Image getSpriteImage(String getter, int x, int y) {
    return sprites.get(getter).getSubImage(x,y);
}

public static Image image(String getter) {
    return sprites.get(getter);
}

public static Image getImage(String getter) {
    return images.get(getter);
}

public static Sound getSound(String getter) {
    return sounds.get(getter);
}
}
```

Comment: what exception do you get? print it with `System.out.println` for example

Comment: just print out the exception

Comment: please add the print stacktace in your question. @squirt706 Thank you

Comment: You know a fair amount of Java, yet you don't know the absolute basics of displaying an exception stacktrace with `e.printStackTrace();`?

Comment: @Enigo You *don't* use `System.out.println` to display exceptions. Using that to display a `NullPointerException` will display `null` which is about as helpful as his current exception "handling".

Comment: gotcha I changed it

Answer (score 1):

there are two kind of exception introduced in `java`.

> **A) Checked Exception (Compile Time)** :- Handle the exception at compile time just to detect any external component or resource dependency (like `FileNotFound`, `IOException`).
>
> **B)  Unchecked Exception (Runtime Exception)** :- This exception came while any logical mistake or any error because of any unexpected situation.(`IndexOutOfBound`, `NullPointer` etc.)

Now Your Question

> why an exception is being thrown when trying to load the .json map file ?

If you try to load any file `.json` in your program which is a external resource loaded from any Storage area (disk, cloud etc). So, there may be a chance of `File` is not present at the storage area.

So, to handle these kind of uncertain situation your program should be ready to handle these kind of situation (this is not a logical error it's a dependency on other resource which is indirect part of Your Code).

this is the reason to put this kind of stuff in `Checked Exception` Segment.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch the exception `e`, you should do something with that `e`. To get more information about where the exception was thrown, use this code:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1); // Because 1 means failure, 0 means OK.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, So I updated my post. I looked up how to read a stack trace (bottom to top) but cannot make any headway World:33 is                              solids = parse((JSONArray)layer.get("data"));

Comment: And the exception is very clear. The JSON parser interprets the `data` field as a string (because the JSON data looks like it), yet you force Java to interpret it as a JSONArray. Look at the JSON data and how it is structured.